# Error: default method not implemented for type 'list' in corrplot in R version 4.1.2

Tags: r

[image]

I'm trying to generate a corrplot with numbers in R and the following error appears: "Error in is.finite(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'"

I tried transforming my list into data frame, but for sure I'm doing something wrong.

Could anyone help me to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Note: I put a picture showing the "x"

Below my code

```
library(corrplot)
x<-read.table("corrplot_2.txt")
x <- as.data.frame(x)  
corrplot(x, method="number")
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Please remove unneccessary code when asking a question. We want to see all that's needed to create the problem, and nothing more.

Comment: You can remove the `as.data.frame` part and should be fine (or do `corrplot(as.matrix(x), method = "number")`)

Comment: Quinten: I will try to do as requested. Thanks

Comment: Caspar V.: Sorry, I just edited the question removing unnecessary parts of the code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Jonathan: Thanks so much. Resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the input of `corrplot` should be a correlation matrix:

> The correlation matrix to visualize, must be square if order is not
> 'original'. For general matrix, please using is.corr = FALSE to
> convert.

So you first have to convert your dataframe to a correlation matrix using `cor` like this:

```
library(corrplot)
x<-read.table("corrplot_2.txt")
x <- as.data.frame(x) 
M <- cor(x)
corrplot(M, method="number")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

You receive this error because `is.finite()` cannot handle data frames / lists:

```r
# example
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(30), ncol=5))
is.finite(df)
```

```r
> is.finite(df)
Error in is.finite(df) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

#### Solution

The functions `lapply()` or `sapply()` allow us to use `is.finite()` for every column:

```r
# solution 1
lapply(df, is.finite)
sapply(df, is.finite)
```

```r
> lapply(df, is.finite)
$V1
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

$V2
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
...

> sapply(df, is.finite)
       V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
...
```

Since we probably don't want an answer for each value individually, but we want to know if *all* of them are finite, we add an `all()`:

```r
# solution 2
all(sapply(df, is.finite))
```

```r
> all(sapply(df, is.finite))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Upon review I realize this isn't what OP was attempting to do. I'll leave the answer anyway for anyone coming across *Error: default method not implemented for type 'list'*.