# How to convert a column of correlations into a correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

This is something that has come up a couple of times in the past year or-so for me and each time causes a minor amount of headache.

Essentially, I have a few times wanted to make a correlation plot using the `corrplot` package but have hit the issue that the data I have will be a single column of correlations, rather than a correlation matrix. What I need then is a top-to-bottom way of converting the data from a table or data frame into a correlation matrix.

I have managed to get MOST of the way to a solution, but haven't properly been able to solve it all yet.

I start by doing the following:

```
filtered_rgMat = melt(df[,c("cohort1", "cohort2", "rg")])

### For reproducibility purposes:

dput(filtered_rgMat)

structure(list(cohort1 = c("AGDS", "AGDS", "AGDS", "AGDS", "AGDS", 
"AGDS", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "FINNGEN", 
"FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GS20K", "GS20K", "GS20K", 
"GS20K", "GS20K", "GS20K", "MGBB", "MGBB", "MGBB", "MGBB", "MGBB", 
"MGBB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB"), cohort2 = c("AOU", 
"FINNGEN", "GBP", "GS20K", "MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "FINNGEN", 
"GBP", "GS20K", "MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", "GBP", "GS20K", 
"MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", "FINNGEN", "GS20K", "MGBB", "UKB", 
"AGDS", "AOU", "FINNGEN", "GBP", "MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", 
"FINNGEN", "GBP", "GS20K", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", "FINNGEN", "GBP", 
"GS20K", "MGBB"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "rg", class = "factor"), value = c(1.147, 
1.133, 0.8881, 0.6743, 0.7062, 0.866, 1.147, 2.81, 0.6095, 0.8929, 
0.4563, 1.796, 1.133, 2.81, 2.388, 1.492, 1.703, 0.7535, 0.8881, 
0.6095, 2.388, 0.8204, 0.2822, 1.641, 0.6743, 0.8929, 1.492, 
0.8204, 0.5716, 1.152, 0.7062, 0.4563, 1.703, 0.2822, 0.5716, 
1.288, 0.866, 1.796, 0.7535, 1.641, 1.152, 1.288)), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, this is an example of the data I have to work with and I then do the following:

```
### Convert data frame into matrix
filtered_rgMat = cast(filtered_rgMat, cohort1 ~ cohort2 )

### Fix row names
rownames(filtered_rgMat) = filtered_rgMat[,1]
filtered_rgMat = filtered_rgMat[,-1]

### Convert the centre of the matrix to have a correlation of 1 (I.e. where the column == the row)
for (i in 1:ncol(filtered_rgMat)) {

  filtered_rgMat[i, i] = 1

}

### Superfluous for the example data but I also convert any other NAs into 0s

for (i in 1:nrow(filtered_rgMat)) {

  is.na(filtered_rgMat[i,]) = 0

}
```

The issue then is that after all of this, despite having what seems to at least **look** like a correlation matrix, corrplot still isn't happy with it and throws the following error:

```
corrplot(filtered_rgMat)

Error in corrplot(filtered_rgMat) : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!`.
```

You can try and fix this by specifically telling corrplot it is not a correlation matrix, but this also doesn't work:

```
corrplot(filtered_rgMat, is.corr = FALSE)

Error in is.finite(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Here, the only other [question answering this I could find on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72840989/error-default-method-not-implemented-for-type-list-in-corrplot-in-r-version-4) basically said to do `cor(df)` which absolutely does not produce the right table here as it changes all the values.

Does anyone have any solutions of where I can go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your data into wide format using `pivot_wider` on the `cohort1` column, ensure your columns and rows are in the correct order using `arrange`,  replace all the `NA` values with 0 using `mutate`, drop the `cohort2` column, convert to a data frame, rename the rows, convert to a matrix and *then* pass to `corrplot`, specifying `is.corr = FALSE`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

filtered_rgMat %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = cohort1, values_from = value) %>%
  arrange(cohort2) %>%
  select(-cohort2) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x))) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `row.names<-`(names(.)) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  corrplot::corrplot(is.corr = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is pretty much the exact solution I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array `ind`ex out of the *cohorts* by making `as.factor` and coercing `as.integer`s. Then initialize an `array`, fill it, and you're there.

```
> df <- df[do.call('order', df[1:2]), ]
> ind <- sapply(df[1:2], \(x) as.integer(as.factor(x)))
> a <- array(dim=replicate(2, length(unique(df$cohort1)), FALSE), 
+            dimnames=lapply(df[1:2], \(x) sort(unique(x))))
> a[ind] <- df$value
> a
         cohort2
cohort1     AGDS    AOU FINNGEN    GBP  GS20K   MGBB    UKB
  AGDS        NA 1.1470  1.1330 0.8881 0.6743 0.7062 0.8660
  AOU     1.1470     NA  2.8100 0.6095 0.8929 0.4563 1.7960
  FINNGEN 1.1330 2.8100      NA 2.3880 1.4920 1.7030 0.7535
  GBP     0.8881 0.6095  2.3880     NA 0.8204 0.2822 1.6410
  GS20K   0.6743 0.8929  1.4920 0.8204     NA 0.5716 1.1520
  MGBB    0.7062 0.4563  1.7030 0.2822 0.5716     NA 1.2880
  UKB     0.8660 1.7960  0.7535 1.6410 1.1520 1.2880     NA
```

Can make a `heatmap` out of it.

```
> heatmap(a, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, revC=TRUE)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(cohort1 = c("AGDS", "AGDS", "AGDS", "AGDS", "AGDS", 
"AGDS", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "AOU", "FINNGEN", 
"FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "FINNGEN", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GS20K", "GS20K", "GS20K", 
"GS20K", "GS20K", "GS20K", "MGBB", "MGBB", "MGBB", "MGBB", "MGBB", 
"MGBB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB", "UKB"), cohort2 = c("AOU", 
"FINNGEN", "GBP", "GS20K", "MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "FINNGEN", 
"GBP", "GS20K", "MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", "GBP", "GS20K", 
"MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", "FINNGEN", "GS20K", "MGBB", "UKB", 
"AGDS", "AOU", "FINNGEN", "GBP", "MGBB", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", 
"FINNGEN", "GBP", "GS20K", "UKB", "AGDS", "AOU", "FINNGEN", "GBP", 
"GS20K", "MGBB"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "rg", class = "factor"), value = c(1.147, 
1.133, 0.8881, 0.6743, 0.7062, 0.866, 1.147, 2.81, 0.6095, 0.8929, 
0.4563, 1.796, 1.133, 2.81, 2.388, 1.492, 1.703, 0.7535, 0.8881, 
0.6095, 2.388, 0.8204, 0.2822, 1.641, 0.6743, 0.8929, 1.492, 
0.8204, 0.5716, 1.152, 0.7062, 0.4563, 1.703, 0.2822, 0.5716, 
1.288, 0.866, 1.796, 0.7535, 1.641, 1.152, 1.288)), row.names = c(NA, 
42L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This does seem like a decent solution and is sort of similar to the route I have previously taken in using `geom_tile()` from `ggplot2`. It's more the desire to actually use the `corrplot()` package which is why I wouldn't say this is exactly what I'm after.